# Generate HTML file from database content in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest, export

I have no idea how to generate the HTML file with the help database content using **REST api**

Currently we are directly storing the HTML source code in **LinkAction** column under **user** table

| Title | LinkAction |
| --- | --- |
| FileName | `<html><head><title>Title</title></head><body><h1>Heading</h1><p>paragraph</p></body></html>` |

My requirement is to generate the **html file** from the html source code and html file name should be the **title** value.

Please help me out this

Comment: This sounds like a wild mix. HTML files are created through a template engine like Thymeleaf. But since you mentioned rest api, maybe there is a front-end framework running? On the other hand you said the HTML is stored in a database, in this case: where does it come from?

Comment: Yes. It's comes from the front end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss");
        String currentDateTime = dateFormatter.format(new Date());
        String filename = "Fingertips_";

        //Creating Excel file and adding Fingertips content to it
        Path cardsExcelPath = Files.createTempFile(filename, ".xlsx");
        FileOutputStream cardsXlsWriter = new FileOutputStream(cardsExcelPath.toFile());

        //Creating zip file and adding above Fingertips Excel file
        Path zipPath = Files.createTempFile(filename, ".zip");
        ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipPath.toFile()));
        zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(cardsExcelPath.getFileName().toString().substring(0,10).concat(".xlsx")));

        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = fingerTipsService.exportAllContentManageToExcel();
        IOUtils.copy(byteArrayInputStream, zipOutputStream);
        cardsXlsWriter.flush();
        cardsXlsWriter.close();
        zipOutputStream.closeEntry();

        List<UserContentDTO> htmlContentList = fingerTipsService.getHtmlContentFilesExport();

        htmlContentList.stream()
                .forEach(userContentDTO -> {
                    try {
                        zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(userContentDTO.getTitle().replaceAll("\\s", "").concat(".html")));
                        Path cardsHtmlPath = Files.createTempFile(userContentDTO.getTitle(), ".html");
                        FileOutputStream cardsHtmlWriter = new FileOutputStream(cardsHtmlPath.toFile());
                        InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(userContentDTO.getLinkactions().getBytes());
                        IOUtils.copy(targetStream, zipOutputStream);
                        cardsHtmlWriter.flush();
                        cardsHtmlWriter.close();
                        zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("came to exception: "+e);
                    }
                });
        zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
        zipOutputStream.flush();
        zipOutputStream.close();

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + filename + currentDateTime)
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/zip"))
                .body(new FileSystemResource(zipPath));
    }
```

service class

```
 public ByteArrayInputStream exportAllContentManageToExcel() {
        List<ContentManage> data = userContentManageRepository.findAll(Sort.by("id").ascending());
        ByteArrayInputStream in = ContentManageExcelExporter.exportAllContentManageToExcelFile(data);
        return in;
    }


    //To ge the HTML source code from Database
    public List<UserContentDTO> getHtmlContentFilesExport()
    {
        List<UserContentDTO> content = userContentManageRepository.getHtmlContentFiles();
        return content;

    }
```

repo class

```
 @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    @Query("select new UserContentDTO( A.id,A.title, A.linkactions)  from ContentManage as A order by A.id")
    List<UserContentDTO> getHtmlContentFiles();
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am able to generate and download the HTML files.
below is my complete source code, it might be help some one.

```
public ResponseEntity<Resource> exportToExcel() throws IOException {
        DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss");
        String currentDateTime = dateFormatter.format(new Date());
        String filename = "cards_";

        List<String> filenameHtml = contentManageService.getHtmlFileName();

        //Creating Execl file and adding Cards content to it
        Path cardsExcelPath = Files.createTempFile(filename, ".xlsx");
        log.info("Cards excel: " + cardsExcelPath.toAbsolutePath());
        FileOutputStream cardsXlsWriter = new FileOutputStream(cardsExcelPath.toFile());

        //Creating zip file and adding above Cards Excel file
        Path zipPath = Files.createTempFile(filename, ".zip");
        log.info("Zipfile path: " + zipPath.toAbsolutePath());
        ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipPath.toFile()));
        zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(cardsExcelPath.getFileName().toString()));

        final byte[] cardsBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = contentManageService.listAll();
        while ((length = byteArrayInputStream.read(cardsBuffer)) >= 0) {
            cardsXlsWriter.write(cardsBuffer);
        }
        cardsXlsWriter.flush();
        cardsXlsWriter.close();

        final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        FileInputStream cardsXlsFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(cardsExcelPath.toFile());
        while ((length = cardsXlsFileInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            zipOutputStream.write(buffer);
        }
        zipOutputStream.closeEntry();


        //Creating HTML file and adding Cards content to it
        for (int i = 0; i < filenameHtml.size(); i++) {
            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(filenameHtml.get(i).concat(".html")));
            Path cardsHtmlPath = Files.createTempFile(filenameHtml.get(i), ".html");
            log.info("Cards html: " + cardsHtmlPath.toAbsolutePath());
            FileOutputStream cardsHtmlWriter = new FileOutputStream(cardsHtmlPath.toFile());

            final byte[] htmlBuffer = new byte[1024];
            int htmlLength;
            List<String> htmlContentList = contentManageService.getHtmlContentFilesExport();
            String initialString = htmlContentList.get(i);
           // ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = contentManageService.getHtmlContentFilesExport();
            InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(initialString.getBytes());
            while ((htmlLength = targetStream.read(htmlBuffer)) >= 0) {
                cardsHtmlWriter.write(htmlBuffer);
            }
            cardsHtmlWriter.flush();
            cardsHtmlWriter.close();

            final byte[] bufferHtml = new byte[1024];
            FileInputStream cardsHtmlFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(cardsHtmlPath.toFile());
            while ((htmlLength = cardsHtmlFileInputStream.read(bufferHtml)) > 0) {
                zipOutputStream.write(bufferHtml);
            }
        }

        zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
        zipOutputStream.flush();
        zipOutputStream.close();

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + filename + currentDateTime)
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/zip"))
                .body(new FileSystemResource(zipPath));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the IOUtils.copy() instead of writing the file.

```
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> exportToExcel() throws IOException {
        DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss");
        String currentDateTime = dateFormatter.format(new Date());
        String filename = "Cards_";
        List<String> filenameHtml = contentManageService.getHtmlFileName();

        //Creating Execl file and adding Cards content to it
        Path cardsExcelPath = Files.createTempFile(filename, ".xlsx");
        log.info("Cards excel: " + cardsExcelPath.toAbsolutePath());
        FileOutputStream cardsXlsWriter = new FileOutputStream(cardsExcelPath.toFile());

        //Creating zip file and adding above Cards Excel file
        Path zipPath = Files.createTempFile(filename, ".zip");
        ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipPath.toFile()));
        zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(cardsExcelPath.getFileName().toString().substring(0,5).concat(".xlsx")));

        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = contentManageService.listAll();
        IOUtils.copy(byteArrayInputStream, zipOutputStream);
        cardsXlsWriter.flush();
        cardsXlsWriter.close();
        zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
        
        //Creating HTML file and adding Cards content to it
        for (int i = 0; i < filenameHtml.size(); i++) {
            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(filenameHtml.get(i).concat(".html").replaceAll("\\s", "")));
            Path cardsHtmlPath = Files.createTempFile(filenameHtml.get(i), ".html");
            log.info("Cards html: " + cardsHtmlPath.toAbsolutePath());
            FileOutputStream cardsHtmlWriter = new FileOutputStream(cardsHtmlPath.toFile());

            List<String> htmlContentList = contentManageService.getHtmlContentFilesExport();
            String initialString = htmlContentList.get(i);
            InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(initialString.getBytes());
            IOUtils.copy(targetStream, zipOutputStream);
            cardsHtmlWriter.flush();
            cardsHtmlWriter.close();
            zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
        }

        zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
        zipOutputStream.flush();
        zipOutputStream.close();

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + filename + currentDateTime)
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/zip"))
                .body(new FileSystemResource(zipPath));
    }
```